# "The constructor Mat(Mat, Rect) is undefined " error in opencv android 2.4.8

Tags: android, opencv

i want to crop image in android but following error occur ..do u peoples have any idea why?

```
    Bitmap oimage=ImgProc_Obj.readImageFromEM();
    //myimageviewer.setImageBitmap(oimage);
    Mat morignal=new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(oimage, morignal);
    Rect myR=new Rect(20 ,20,300,300);//here is error"The constructor Mat(Mat, Rect) is undefined"
    Mat croped=new Mat(morignal,myR);
    Mat test=new Mat();
```

thanks in advance ..

Comment: [who says so](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#Mat(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Rect)) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your imports. May be you are using `android.graphics.Rect` instead of `org.opencv.core.Rect`, that is expected by the Mat constructor.